# Best practice for long running SQL queries in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have an action method which needs to complete 15~52 long running SQL queries (all of them are similar, each takes more than 5 seconds to complete) according to user-selected dates.

After doing a lot of research, it seems the best way to do this without blocking the ASP.Net thread is to use async/await task methods With SQL Queries:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Action() {   
    // initialization stuff

    // create tasks to run async SQL queries
    ConcurrentBag<Tuple<DateTime, List<long>>> weeklyObsIdBag = 
        new ConcurrentBag<Tuple<DateTime, List<long>>>();
    Task[] taskList = new Task[reportDates.Count()];
    int idx = 0;
    foreach (var reportDate in reportDates) { //15 <= reportDates.Count() <= 52
        var task = Task.Run(async () => {
            using (var sioDbContext = new SioDbContext()) {
                var historyEntryQueryable = sioDbContext.HistoryEntries
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .AsQueryable<HistoryEntry>();
                var obsIdList = await getObsIdListAsync(
                    historyEntryQueryable, 
                    reportDate
                );
                weeklyObsIdBag.Add(new Tuple<DateTime,List<long>>(reportDate, obsIdList));
            }
        });
        taskList[idx++] = task;
    }
    //await for all the tasks to complete
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    // consume the results from long running SQL queries, 
    // which is stored in weeklyObsIdBag
}

private async Task<List<long>> getObsIdListAsync(
    IQueryable<HistoryEntry> historyEntryQueryable, 
    DateTime reportDate
) {
    //apply reportDate condition to historyEntryQueryable

    //run async query
    List<long> obsIdList = await historyEntryQueryable.Select(he => he.ObjectId)
        .Distinct()
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    return obsIdList;
}
```

After making this change, the time taken to complete this action is greatly reduced since now I am able to execute multiple (15~52) async SQL queries simultaneously and await for them to complete rather than running them sequentially. However, users start to experience lots of time out issues, such as :

```
(from Elmah error log) 
"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. 
 This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was 
 reached."
"The wait operation timed out"
```

Is it caused by thread starvation? I got a feeling that I might be using too many threads from thread pool to achieve what I want, but I thought it shouldn't be a problem because I used async/await to prevent all the threads from being blocked.

If things won't work this way, then what's the best practice to execute multiple long running SQL queries?

Comment: consumer-producer pattern will help here + message broker like [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). Clients can just check with JS state of the tasks while they are being processed.

Comment: Windows Services other solution for long running tasks

Answer (score 5):

Consider limiting the number of concurrent tasks being executed, for example:

```
int concurrentTasksLimit = 5;
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
foreach (var reportDate in reportDates) { //15 <= reportDates.Count() <= 52
    var task = Task.Run(async () => {
        using (var sioDbContext = new SioDbContext()) {
            var historyEntryQueryable = sioDbContext.HistoryEntries
                .AsNoTracking()
                .AsQueryable<HistoryEntry>();
            var obsIdList = await getObsIdListAsync(
                historyEntryQueryable, 
                reportDate
            );
            weeklyObsIdBag.Add(new Tuple<DateTime,List<long>>(reportDate, obsIdList));
        }
    });
    taskList.Add(task);
    if (concurrentTasksLimit == taskList.Count)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
        // before clearing the list, you should get the results and store in memory (e.g another list) for later usage...
        taskList.Clear();
    }
}
//await for all the remaining tasks to complete
if (taskList.Any())
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

Take note I changed your `taskList` to an actual `List<Task>`, it just seems easier to use it, since we need to add/remove tasks from the list.

Also, you should get the results before clearing the `taskList`, since you are going to use them later.

Comment: This seems to be a good way to avoid too many concurrent tasks (threads). But this also means I can only run a limited number of long running queries at a time, and it would take longer to complete all the queries which leads to bad performance. Users won't be happy about it :(

Comment: @winhow that's true, but I recommend you to do some tests, because I really believe this won't reduce so much performance. I had this same problem once, and I didn't notice such a loss of performance.